# Cannot comment and annotate a specific .pdf file with acrobat reader

Tags: macos, adobe-acrobat

I have Acrobat Reader 10.1.4 on mac (10.6.8). For some reason, I can't add comments to one specific file. It works okay for other files. The comment button is not clickable. I am sure I have read and write access to the file. What could be the problem?

**Edit:** Uninstalling Reader 10 and installing Reader 11 solved the problem for some reason.

Comment: You can or cannot add comments?  Your second sentence is not clear in my opinion.

Comment: You can add comments to any PDF file, **unless security has been applied to the document to prohibit commenting**. from http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1670579&seqNum=3

Comment: @Ramhound I made the sentence more clear.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, someone else has a copy of the same file, but they can annotate it.

Comment: When you have the document open and hit Cmd-D, and switch to the Security tab, is everything allowed?

Comment: @MaxWyss It says Comments: Not allowed

Comment: OK, so, it is either that the document has restrictions, or that it has been created using LiveCycle Designer, or that (despite knowing better) Reader is restricted.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate Is that other user using the same PDF software? Not all PDF software respects the editing restrictions. Of course, everything produced by Adobe does.

Comment: @BrianDuddy They were both Adobe reader but different versions.